# Optimize Ionic and AngularFire2 auth providers

Tags: ionic3, angularfire2

I got a generic question about what is the most performance "cost-effectiveness" with auth provider.

I got an Ionic 3 app with 6 providers performing various actions. In almost each of them, I need to know who is the current user connected.

So in my `AuthProvider`I got something like this in my constructor

```
public userId: string

this.afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.userId = user.uid
        console.log('AuthProvider – Connected User is ' + this.userId)
      }
    });
```

The in all other providers, I `import` my `AuthProvider` and retrieve my `userId`

Is this the best way to proceed, rather than subscribe on each of my providers?

Is there any limitation having provider calling each other?

Thanks for any input on that subject.

Comment: A lot of responses I see on this say to store the result locally and access it there, with the pages that need to know when the user changes monitor the subscription to change the local setting.

Comment: So the use of localStorage still an actual option! Good to know